# iMac Internal Hard Drive Not Visible, Won't Mount; Currently running off External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, imac, disk-utility, crash

My iMac (27-inch, mid-2010) crashed and refused to reboot. I was able to reboot it from an external drive and attempted to erase and resurrect the internal drive; after several attempts, the drive ceased to be visible to Disk Utility and am afraid it may be physically defective. Is there a way of mounting the disk and confirming its status?

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like your hard drive has failed.

Have you tried booting up and using Apple Hardware Test? To do this hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key down while booting up.

If AHT doesn't load, you can also trying running it from the internet by holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> keys while booting up.

Give this a try and let us know how you go.

Comment: This was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open disk utility and repair the partition on the physical unit that is not booting.

If the unit is making strange noises I'd take it to a qualified center to clone the content of the unit to an SSD unit.